# Не работает анализ тональности английского текста с Vader в Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x, текст, nlp, анализ

```
MyText = Reviews["reviewText"]

myVader = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for EachReview in MyText:
    print EachReview,
sentiment = myVader.polarity_scores(EachReview)
print "\n\t" + str(sentiment)
```

Result:

```
B e s t   g u i t a r   i n s t r u c t i o n a l   v i d e o   t h a t   h a v e   s e e n   i n   m y   2 0   y e a r s   o f   p l a y i n g .   C o m e s   w i t h   v i d e o   t a b s   w h i c h   i s   g r e a t   t o o ! 
{'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
```

Почему Vader работает не корректно? Программа читает файл Json....Выглядит это, как нормальный текстовый файл с комментариями.

Есть пример рабочего кода:

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

sentences = ["The plot was good, but the characters are uncompelling and the dialog is not great.", "A really bad, horrible book.","At least it isn't a horrible book."]

myVader = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for SingleReview in sentences:
    print SingleReview
    sentiment = myVader.polarity_scores(SingleReview)
    print "\n\t" + str(sentiment)
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас анализ только для последнего элемента в списке происходит так как вне цикла обращения к myVader идут — отступы имеют значение в Питон коде:

```
"вне цикла"
for item in collection:
    "внутри цикла"
    "внутри цикла"
"вне цикла"
"вне цикла"
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я добавила ненужный цикл.
в коде:

```
`myVader = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for EachReview in ReviewText:
    print EachReview,
sentiment = myVader.polarity_scores(ReviewText)
print "\n" + str(sentiment)`
```

Python делит каждое слово на буквы, и поэтому не может совершить анализ тональности. Анализ с Vader тональности производится только если имеются полноценные слова. 
Поэтому и результатом стало: Result: B e s t g u i t a r i n s t r u c t i o n a l v i d e o t h a t h a v e s e e n i n m y 2 0 y e a r s o f p l a y i n g . C o m e s w i t h v i d e o t a b s w h i c h i s g r e a t t o o ! {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}, просто все разделилось знаками пробелов! Ужас, просто))))

В данном случае мне было необходимо всего лишь:

```
`myVader = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sentiment = myVader.polarity_scores(ReviewText)
print "\n" + str(sentiment)
print MyText`
```

Видимо это связано с тем, что в моем документе отзывы (комментарии) разделены уже на отдельные части, в отличие от примера работающего кода, в котором список строк необходимо разделить и проанализировать отдельно.